# How to turn-off 10-bit video output from PC to TV?

Tags: windows-7, video, amd-radeon

How do you disable 10-bit video output from an AMD/ATI 6000 series card in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow:

1. If you do not have it already, download and install the [Catalyst Control Center](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-catalyst/pages/catalyst.aspx) (CCC).
2. Click `[Start] -> All Programs -> Catalyst Control Center`.
3. Locate the checkbox called *Enable 10-bit pixel format support*.

   In the newest version of CCC, just type *10-bit* in the search area.

   The checkbox used to be under *Workstation*, but this can differ from version to version.
4. Uncheck the aforementioned checkbox and click `[OK]`.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the latest CCC, but there is no Workstation and there was no search result for 10-bit.